# JTable data update flickering, client-server model

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I know many times already talked about this problem but for me non of them helped. I have a client-server application which communicate via sockets.

The method is the following:

1. Client make a request to the server
2. Server receive the request, process
3. Send back the requested data via XML
4. The JTable update / populate with new XML data

The client request happen every 5th second so the table flickering is very frequent.

What do you think how able to solve this issue, stop the flickering completely and keep frequent update?

Regards

Comment: What is the data? Does it change significantly from request to request, or is it just new, additional data being added each time?

Comment: Does "every 5th second update" mean an update rate of 0.2 Hz or 5 Hz?

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if it could be a threading issue.  When working with Swing, you want to make sure that tasks such as making a call to the server are done on a thread other than the UI thread.  Then when you update the table, this must be on the swing thread.